# how to install usb_cam on groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried installing the usb_cam driver by following the instruction from

> wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/StackInstallation

but it seems the instructions is outdated for groovy and I am currently stuck

What is the current alternative to

> rosmake --rosdep-install

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109041/how-to-install-usb_cam-on-groovy/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're on Ubuntu and installed via apt, there is a ros-groovy-usb-cam package that you can install.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-usb-cam
```

---

Originally posted by [spease](https://answers.ros.org/users/9736/spease/) with karma: 46 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2013-12-12**:
You can also look at the uvc_camera package. It supports usb cameras.